# "bower install underscore" getting error in node.js

Tags: node.js

```
"bower install underscore" getting error 

bower ENOGIT          git is not installed or not in the path
```

I want to use static resources in node.js website so I am installing underscore using bower but I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also getting the same error and the Solution is first check if the "Git" is installed or not in the system and if not please install it.

After installation open "Git Bash" from windows and go to your project (same way you go in command prompt using "cd path").

Then run the same "Bower install command", It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Git and make sure the git command is globally accessible or at least accessible for bower.

The msysGit project has a handy installer to make things easier. (assuming you're running Windows)
http://msysgit.github.com/

Found this solution here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git